# In which coordinate system are these coordinates: 50075482, 14430068?

Tags: coordinates, convert, latitude-longitude, wgs84, czech-republic

I have multiple locations saved in WGS84 - it looks like e.g. latitude: 50075482, logitude: 14430068.

I tried to search it on the map this way: 12.345678, 87.654321, but it doesn't match the place it should be - it is several meters away. I just need to get proper GPS coordinates. Am I doing it the right way? Is this actually WGS84?

Or do I just need to convert it somehow to use it?

It should be Legerova - Rumunská street in Prague, Czech republic. I can get this place by dividing the numbers with a dot, but it doesn't look like WGS84.

Comment: Have you tried decimal minutes? Can't say much, when I don't see some example coordinates, so I can have a look which value domains are there. Would also help to know which region on the earth it should be.

Comment: what is the source of your data? your provider should be able to answer the projection system of your data.

Comment: It could be in degrees decimal minutes or degrees minutes seconds, but I would expect the points to be farther off if so.

Comment: if i put these coordinates in google maps i am quite near to rumunska street (https://maps.google.at/maps?q=50.075482,+14.430068&hl=de&ll=50.075485,14.43007&spn=0.007244,0.021136&sll=50.073915,14.432902&sspn=0.007244,0.021136&t=m&z=16). Depending on what type of GPS you use, and how long you did take to record the position, I think thats not so bad. Urban Areas can be nasty for good quality GPS positioning. I don'tthink the coordinates are misinterpreted, they are just the way they are.

Comment: It indeed seems that these might me WGS coordinates, just with non-standard notation. Can you provide a picture with more point examples to see is there any consistent pattern with displacement.
It might be that the original data was incorrectly transformed.

Comment: what map are you talking about?

Answer (score 8):

This is not WGS84 System, WGS system is an angular system so the latitude value cannot exceed 90, and the longitude can not exceed 360. You need to figure out the coordinate system of your data, which i guess might be in WGS84 projected system which measures distance in meters. Any GIS softwares can convert it e.g. Quantum GIS.

Roughly: 3 sec in WGS84 system would correspond to 100m in WGS84 projected system.

The numbers provided are not the latitude and longitude, but easting and northing of the place. These will be correctly interpreted by google maps.

Answer (score 0):

In python you can use something like this:

```
newWGS84 = original.to_crs({'proj':'longlat', 'ellps':'WGS84', 'datum':'WGS84'})
newWGS84.plot()
```

PS: More information is here https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_crs.html